# Получить список баз по имени таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо получить список баз, в которых присутствует таблицы.

Подобное делал с таблицами - поиск по полю. Но вот как вывернуть это для баз, не могу придумать.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME Like '%column%'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы просто отобразить все базы:

```
SHOW DATABASES
```

Чтобы что-то отфильтровать по названию таблицы ([TABLE_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html) - это и есть база данных):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'какая-то таблица'
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%table_name%'
```